# Passar valor para componente com Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu projeto

```
 1. App.vue (Arquivo principal)
 2. App.vue (outro arquivo que fica dentro da pasta paginas)
 3. Dashboard.vue (filho do 2 app.vue)
```

Dentro do meu segundo app.vue eu chamo o `component Menu`, a questão é, como eu faria para passar os dados para o `component Menu`?

OBS: É um dashboard, e ao logar, tenho os dados do usuario, que quero colocar no Menu

**`index.js`**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'DashboardA',
          path: '/',
          component: Dashboard,
          meta: { requiresAuth: true }
        },
        {
          path: '/cardapio',
          name: 'Cardapio',
          component: Itens
        },
        {
          path: '/categorias',
          name: 'Categorias',
          component: Categorias
        },
        {
          path: '/categorias',
          name: 'Categorias',
          component: Categorias
        },
        {
          path: '/subcategorias',
          name: 'SubCategorias',
          component: SubCategorias
        },
        {
          path: '/clientes',
          name: 'Clientes',
          component: Clientes
        }
      ],
      component: AppDashboard
    }
  ]
})
```

Eu sei que, se eu chamo o componente na pagina, consigo passar dados via `props`, mas nesse caso, que vou para o `Dashboard`, mas o menu está em `App.vue`, como faria?

Comment: Você tem alguma parte da aplicação gerenciando estado global? Vuex? Senão vai ter de criar um mecanismo para isso. Não posso responder em detalhes agora, mas ver https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Comment: Não, eu não uso `vuex`

Comment: Uma boa alternativa nesse caso pode ser usando event bus:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Answer (score 1):

1. Instale [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org)
2. Crie [uma store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html) para os dados do usuário
3. [Atualize os dados](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) do funcionário ao fazer login
4. [Consuma os dados](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) em qualquer componente

Comment: Eu já resolvi, mas de qualquer forma, `Vuex` é para controle de estado, não é recomendado usar para controle de informações de login.

Comment: De onde você tirou que "não é recomendado para informações de login"? Se você se refere a dados sensíveis (como senha), isso obviamente não deve ficar armazenado no frontend, mas se for dados não-sensíveis (como nome do usuário, data do último acesso etc), é natural que seja salvo no vuex.

Comment: Ao se trabalhar com login, não se trata de apenas nome de usuario e ultimo acesso, falamos de `id`, é uma pessima pratica utilizar o `Vuex` para isso, até porque, o proprio pessoal do `Vuex` diz que é para usar `Vuex` apenas se o projeto realmente necessitar, não vejo a necessidade da utilização do mesmo para login, controle de estados, essa é a questão, se for utilizar para uma ou duas coisas, desnecessario.